# How to make a floating chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Actually I am fairly new to chrome extensions, I just wanted to create a chrome extension in the form of a floating window, but am unable to find any way to do it, Is it possible, and if it is, please tell how could I do it?

I tried using chrome.windows.create and some other methods but none of them worked in the way I want it to.

Comment: Generally there's no way. You'll have to use document-in-picture but that's limited to just one such window or add the UI as a DOM element to the web page, which won't work on chrome:// pages and such.

Comment: Ok thanks, would do something else then